# GtkPaned widget for arbitrary geometries?

Tags: gtk, panes

I would like my application window to be divided into rectangles with sides perpendicular to the window borders. The number of rectangles would normally be quite large, and the user should be able to resize the rectangles.

Is there a Gtk widget which would allow for that? GTkPaned comes close - by embedding several GtkPaned widgets one can get such rectangle disivisons, but not all of them are possible - one obvious constraint is that there must be an edge which spans the whole window either horizontally or vertically. The simplest arrangement I know of which doesn't have this property, and so can't be built with Gtkpaned, is: one square in the middle and four rectangles of the same size each, around the square.

Is there a widget which allows for such arbitrary resizable rectangle arrangements in Gtk?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to have the dividing lines draggable, then use a `GtkGrid`:

```
grid = Gtk.Grid()
grid.attach(widget1, 0, 0, 3, 1)
grid.attach(widget2, 3, 0, 1, 3)
grid.attach(widget3, 0, 1, 1, 3)
grid.attach(widget4, 1, 3, 3, 1)
grid.attach(widget5, 1, 1, 2, 2)

# 1112
# 3552
# 3552
# 3444
```